# Input border CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with my input borders. When I change the border width property, it changes the width of the entire input. However, I want the input's width to be 100%. Here's my code:

CSS

```css
#wrapper {
      width: 170px;
    }
    textarea {
      border-color: #eee;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
    label, textarea, input {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
    input {
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <form>
        <label for="comments">Comments</label>
        <textarea name="comments" rows="5"></textarea>
        <label for="date">Date</label>
        <input type="text" name="date">
        <label for="time">Time</label>
        <input type="text" name="time">
        <label for="longitude">Longitude</label>
        <input type="text" name="logitude">
        <label for="latitude">Latitude</label>
        <input type="text" name="latitude">
   </form>
<div>
```

Notice how the inputs stretch almost as far as the text area, but not quite. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use the `box-sizing` to `border-box` to add `width` as well, as `border` too takes up its own width:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 170px;
}
textarea {
  border-color: #eee;
  border-width: 1px;
}
label, textarea, input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
input {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <form>
    <label for="comments">Comments</label>
    <textarea name="comments" rows="5"></textarea>
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="date">
    <label for="time">Time</label>
    <input type="text" name="time">
    <label for="longitude">Longitude</label>
    <input type="text" name="logitude">
    <label for="latitude">Latitude</label>
    <input type="text" name="latitude">
  </form>
</div>
```

**Explanation**

The CSS box model, by default is `content-width` defines the total dimension as:

```
width = contentWidth + paddingLeftWidth + borderLeftWidth
height = contentHeight + paddingLeftHeight + borderLeftHeight
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [binvisions.com](http://www.binvisions.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/css-box-model-border-content_590x328.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Two options.

First, you can use `calc()` to allow for this.

```
input { width: calc(100% - 2px); }
```

...where 2px is the combined left and right border widths.

Next, you can use `box-sizing: border-box`, which tells the browser to include any padding and border within the width, rather than making it extra as currently.

Comment: Please, don't advice something that's non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

As you set the wrapper width by 170px and the input is inside the wrapper, when you set its width to 100% it will be 170px